# Accessing a form field 'error' on view

Tags: django

I want to know in my view, if a certain field raised an error, that way I can send some values to the template (index of current tab (using a javascript tab widget)).
Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can definitely access your form errors in your view. Each bound Form instance has an errors attribute that gives you a dictionary mapping field name to error-message lists:

```
>>> f = ContactForm({'subject': 'Hello', 'message':''})
>>> f.errors
{'message':[u'This field is required.']}
```

You can access individual fields as follows:

```
>>> if f['subject'].errors:
        values = [Add values to send to template]
```

Comment: Good, I was using something like if "subject" in f.errors: ... But this is better, I was printing f.errors which gives the html string